# Cannot use generic with Util class in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, generics

I have a Util class and there is a static method called `csvToEmployees`. In order to use this method with different type of request classes, I am trying to convert the class as shown below that takes generic parameter:

```
public class CsvHelper<T> {

    public List<T> csvToEmployees(InputStream is) {
        
        //code omitted

        for (CSVRecord rec : records) {
            T employee = new T(
                    // ...
            );
            employees.add(employee);
        }
        return employees;
    }
}
```

I call this method from my service by injecting this util class as shown below:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeService {

    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private final CsvHelper<EmployeeRequest> helper;

    public void create(MultipartFile file) {
        List<Employee> employees = helper.csvToEmployees(file.getInputStream()).stream()
                .map(EmployeeRequestMapper::mapToEntity)
                .toList();
       
        // ...
    }
}
```

My problems are:

**1.** Is the implementation approach above is ok or not? I mean assuming that there are different kind of requests with the same fields, is using generic with that approach ok?

**2.** I get "*Type parameter 'T' cannot be instantiated directly*" error in the `T employee = new T(` line of util class. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can't. How would you know the constructor signature (or if it's even visible) without knowing the class?

Comment: Why does it have to be generics?

Comment: You might want to look at [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) or some other reflection-based solution if you're constructing types dynamically.

Comment: @shmosel Any example please for this situation?

Comment: @ChengThao Just assume that the fields in the request class are the same, but they are different types. Then I may want to use generic. But not sure if it was a bad idea. What would you suggest? Any clarification please?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Are you only creating `Employee` objects here?  What different generics are you thinking about?  In general, you may be able to do something here by writing `public static List<T> csvToEmployees(InputStream is, Function<String, T> parseFn)` where `parseFn` accepts a function that describes how to read in a `T` from a string.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks a lot, but still the same error when I use it without static. I think I cannot make it static as the class takes static parameters.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear to me why your code is or isn't static, why you're designing it one way or another.  Does `CSVHelper` have any other methods?

Comment: It does not any other method. Just assume that I want to use the same csv writer method for different type of request by passing Generic of that type. What would you do? It is not important that the method is static or not. The important part is using generic for that util method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution, in my opinion, is just creating multiple csvToObject methods inside the classes that you need to process.

I mean if you already know that you’re transforming a stream into a list of employees (it’s “hard coded” in the service method) why would you need to use generics? Just use the method for employees instead.